# What is he? vs Who is he?

Tags: grammar

What is he? -- Does the question refer to what he is doing for a living?

Who is he? -- Does it refer to his name? For example, he is Peter.

Comment: Normally, "Who is he?" asks a person's name, or possibly his position or occupation.  "Who is he?"  "He's Joe.  He's a cop."  "What is he?" asks chiefly for a person's nature, position, or occupation, not his name.  "What is he?" "He's a cop [as opposed to a soldier or fireman, say]" or "He's the commander of the submarine" or "He [Spock] is a Vulcan."  There is some overlap with those questions.

Comment: It depends on context. If you ask "who is Sylvia?" for example, you're not asking for her name.

Comment: Shakespeare doesn't answer the question "Who is Sylvia?" in his poem from "Two Gentlemen of Verona", but he does answer the question that follows: "What is she, / That all our swains commend her?"  We are told "Holy, fair, and wise is she".

Comment: English is not Russian, there is no Kto Joe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What is he?"

You're asking about his job. For example:

A: What's he?
B: He's a painter.

"Who is he?"

You're asking about either his name  or position; sometimes both. For example,

A: Who's he?
B: Oh, he's Mr. Wilcox, the head of the division.

Answer (score 0):

"Who" refers to personal identification (usually the name). If someone asks you "who is he/she" or "who are they," they are basically asking for the narrowest possible definition that could apply to the subject.

"What," on the other hand, essentially asks you to provide information about the subject's wider category. This could mean a job (programmer), a species (human), or anything else that provides you information more general than identification. "Oh, what a cute dog! What is he?" "He's a Corgi." Since there are many possible wider categories, "what" tends to be a lot more context-sensitive than "who."